# I'm unable to send body part in fetch API JSN

Tags: javascript, post, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch altitude data from `api.opentopodata.org` but I have some problems:
Here is my code:

```
let dataSEND = {
    "locations":
    [
      {
       "latitude": lat,
       "longitude": lon
      }
    ]

  };



 const elev_response = await fetch('https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/gebco2020',{ 
 method: 'POST',
 headers:{
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(dataSEND),

 });
```

And I get this error

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/gebco2020' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So disabling CORS

```
 const elev_response = await fetch('https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/gebco2020',{ 
 method: 'POST',
 headers:{
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(dataSEND),
  mode: 'no-cors'
 });
```

I get another error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
>
> "error": "No locations provided. Add locations in a query string: ?
> locations=lat1,lon1|lat2,lon2.",
> "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
> }

as the body part was not sent.

The API as curl works well
https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/gebco2020?locations=10,10

I get:

```
{
"results": [
{
"dataset": "gebco2020",
"elevation": 515,
"location": {
"lat": 10,
"lng": 10
}
}
],
"status": "OK"
}
```

Some help please   :)

Comment: the CORS issue is because you're sending this from a page loaded `file:///` therefore no cross origin requests will work

Comment: Ok, but disabling CORS  I get another error

Comment: there's no such thing as *disabling CORS* - CORS is a server side function to control what clients can or can not get

Answer (score 0):

Using the documentation I verified the request it's a GET using query params.

https://www.opentopodata.org/datasets/gebco2020/

Then you need do something like this:

```
await fetch('https://api.opentopodata.org/v1/gebco2020?locations=37.6535,-119.4105').then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => console.log(data))
```